# Is this a bug in Stack Exchange? - Duplicated title, same answers, different order

Tags: support

When I am on this page https://english.stackexchange.com/users/127726/chasly-from-uk

I see two instances of a question listed separately.

[What is a good word I can use for the talking I do with myself in my mind?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262787/what-is-a-good-word-i-can-use-for-the-talking-i-do-with-myself-in-my-mind/262793#262793)

[What is a good word I can use for the talking I do with myself in my mind?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262787/what-is-a-good-word-i-can-use-for-the-talking-i-do-with-myself-in-my-mind/262791#262791)

Both question and answers are identical except that the answers appear in a different order.

What's going on?

Comment: Those are the same question.  Answers with the same vote count are randomly ordered to avoid fast answerers from getting all the votes.

Comment: It's listed twice in that user's page because they submitted two separate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are two separate answers by the same user, hence the "duplicate" display (not really duplicate - they are simply both listed, with the question title).

As for why they come up with a different order - they have the same score (score = upvotes - downvotes). Whenever page is loaded any posts with the same score are shuffled randomly within that score - this is done so there is less potential for voting bias (simply because an answer is displayed earlier in the list it can get more votes).